What is the name of this movie- red haired sea demon avenges refugees killed at sea?
I've Googled this forever!  No luck at all.  Mainly just because of too much chaff, I'm sure it's in there somewhere.
I saw it a few years ago; I think it was made in mid-late '90s.  
A production company filming a movie in the Caribbean hires a beautiful long, curly red-haired actress for the lead role that oddly has no history- doesn't exist at all.  
Suddenly, people start dying, I believe all in water-related accidents.  One of the set staff is investigating and discovers footage on the laptop of the director and some of the other dead shooting and/or throwing off a boat at sea a bunch of refugees or natives. 
He suspects someone is avenging the deaths. (He had no part in it, so he's ok).  He realizes it's the red-haired actress.  
In the closing scene she shows him that she's a supernatural being- some kind of sea god/demon- rather frighteningly.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
